# how to Diplay consecutive date

Tags: sql

Hello I have  query to show count and sum of amount for a product that is sold everyday. How do I display for all the date in a week regardless has sold a product or not

Answer (score 0):

code to generate a series of consecutive dates of current week

```sql
SELECT generate_series(
  date_trunc('week', now()),
  date_trunc('week', now()) + interval'6days',
  interval'1day'
)::DATE AS x
```

then you can left-join your aggregated data to it

Comment: In order to be able to join against this result. `generate_series()` should be used in the `FROM` clause, not the select list.

Comment: yes ```SELECT smthn FROM generate_series(..) AS x LEFT JOIN yourdata ON x=..```